# How to get count of distinct values meeting certain minimum date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with the following structure (simplified):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/1" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 123,
    \"date_created\": \"2015-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/2" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 123,
    \"date_created\": \"2014-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/3" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 123,
    \"date_created\": \"2013-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/4" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 456,
    \"date_created\": \"2015-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/5" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 456,
    \"date_created\": \"2012-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/aggtest/6" -d "{
    \"user_id\": 456,
    \"date_created\": \"2011-05-12T10:29:49-04:00\"
}"
```

How can i get a count of `user_ids` which was created before or after a certain date? E.g. In aforementioned documents there will be only one unique `user_id` who has records after 2012.

In mongodb it's fairly simple. Using aggregation framework i can transform documents where will be one unique user id and its minimum creation date. Then just filter results by date and count. I'm unable to write similar query in elasticsearch. Any help appreciated.

In SQL this query should look like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM aggtest WHERE date_created >= 2015 AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM aggtest WHERE date_created < 2015)
```

Comment: Be aware that your example shows *two* unique `user_id` records after 2012, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the comments I think I understand what you're asking, though it's not completely clear from the original question.

It sounds like you want to find unique `user_id`s for which there are `creation_date`s after some date, but none before.

I can't think of a way to do that with your current data structure, but if you're willing to reorganize your data using the [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html), it's fairly straightforward to set up the query you want.

To test it, I set up an index with two types, as follows:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "_id": {
            "path": "user_id"
         },
         "properties": {
            "user_id": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      },
      "creation_date": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "user"
         }, 
         "properties": {
            "date_created": {
               "type": "date",
               "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I indexed the data you provided using the new schema:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":123}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":123}}
{"date_created":"2015-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":123}}
{"date_created":"2014-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":123}}
{"date_created":"2013-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":456}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":456}}
{"date_created":"2015-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":456}}
{"date_created":"2012-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
{"index":{"_type":"creation_date","_parent":456}}
{"date_created":"2011-05-12T10:29:49-04:00"}
```

Now I can get back what you're asking (assuming I understand correctly) with the following query. In words, I want to filter the (parent) `user` documents by those who have at least one (child) `creation_date` greater than or equal to `"2012-05-12"`, but DO NOT have any (child) `creation_date`s less than `"2012-05-12"`, and then I want to show those ids in an aggregation (the aggregation is sort of redundant here, but I'm assuming your real index is more complicated so it could be useful not to return the full `user` documents):

```
POST /test_index/user/_search?search_type=count
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "has_child": {
                        "type": "creation_date",
                        "filter": {
                           "range": {
                              "date_created": {
                                 "gte": "2012-05-12"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "not": {
                        "filter": {
                           "has_child": {
                              "type": "creation_date",
                              "filter": {
                                 "range": {
                                    "date_created": {
                                       "lt": "2012-05-12"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "distinct_user_ids": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "distinct_user_ids": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 123,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is all the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/1fbe448a85b9c74cb25cd5245d4e77f1eec46ea7

Answer (score 0):

Use the cardinality aggregation to get the distinct count of values in a field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

Combine the aggregation with the range filter to limit the results to a time frame: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html

Example:

```
GET /test/aggtest/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "range" : {
                "date_created" : {
                    "gte": "2015-09-01"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "distinct_user_ids" : {
      "cardinality" : {
        "field" : "user_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will get an aggregation result with a `doc_count` for the `distinct_user_ids` aggregation.

Comment: My question is a little more complex. I need to exclude `user_ids` from count who have an entry with date before given date. I want to get users only with `date_created` `gte` 2012-09-01. In my example it will be only one user_id with id `123`.

Comment: That's exaclty why the query uses a range filter. The aggregated user_id count respects that filter and only shows the number of distinct user_ids created after 2012-09-01.

Comment: You don't understand me clearly. I'll try to explain differently. I need to count only user_ids who fit it date range and also don't have any records out of it. In other words - user with id 456 have a record with creation date at 2011. I want to count only users with date range of 2012 (across whole index), so this user_id should be excluded from count because it has record out of specified date range.

Comment: In SQL it should look something like this: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM aggtest WHERE date_created >= 2015 AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM aggtest WHERE date_created < 2015)`

Comment: The question doesn't explain that restriction very clearly.

Comment: I can think of a way to do what you want, but it will require changing your data schema. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do what you want with the data structure you have.